# How to acces Arrays form another document class

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am developing a step sequencer for the college project. I created a document class for every button and all the code for each button is in the button class. when the button is pressed the sound is pushed into the array in this class. How can I access that array in the main class so when the button is pressed it will play the sound at a current step

```
public var tomsoundArray:Array = new Array();


    [Embed(source = "sounds/tom.mp3")]

    public var tomSoundClass:Class;

    public var tomSound:Sound = new tomSoundClass() as Sound;

    public function TomButton()
    {
        // constructor code
        //checkIfBtActive = true;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkButtonState);




    }
    public function checkButtonState(event:MouseEvent)
    {


        if (this.alpha == 1)
        {
            this.alpha = 0.5;
            tomsoundArray.push(tomSound);
            trace(tomsoundArray);
            tomSound.play();
            trace("ButtonActive: " + this.alpha);
            trace(this.parent.name);
            trace(this.name);


        }
        else if (this.alpha == 0.5)
        {
            this.alpha = 1;
            tomsoundArray.splice(0);    
            trace(tomsoundArray);



            trace("Button Deactivated: " + this.alpha);


        }
```

Comment: what I have to do in the main class I have to loop through the array of tracks and buttons in each track and then check if alpha of the button is less than one if is play the sound form the array but the array is in the button class,  and I have 96 instances of a button so if i target each instance I am gonna end up with 3000 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some access to the buttons in the Main class.

If you've added the buttons to the stage manually, you need to give them instance names. Click on a button on stage and put some name in the 'properties' panel, 'instance name' input field.

Then in your main class you should be able to access: this.myButtonName.tomsoundArray